# Votes gone missing?

Tags: support, voting

About a week ago, I made an answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321459/what-is-the-difference-between-str-null-and-str0-0-in-c).

As of two or three days ago:

- I had 1 downvote on my answer. (there were actually 2, but one was revoked on the first day)
- JaredPar's answer had a score of 26 at one point. ([he got the badge for it too](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/24/good-answer?userid=23283))

But now when I looked back on the question, I noticed this:

- The last downvote on my answer has disappeared ***with no effect on my rep***. (I always get +2 for a revoked downvote even if I've already hit the repcap.*)
- I *think* I might have lost an upvote. I don't remember...
- JaredPar's answer is now at 23. ***He lost 3 votes?***

So I'm wondering what happened? Were those votes actually revoked? Or did some (three) accounts that voted on it get burned/merged? I know it doesn't matter at all, but curiosity kills me...

*Note that although I always get +2 on a revoked downvote. This is just the visible rep. I don't actually get 2 points back in the rep-audit page if I've hit the repcap.

Comment: It does indeed look like at least one of the users that voted got deleted. There are several comments whose users no longer link.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible explanation of what might have happened:

1. You got a downvote (-2 rep).
2. You got enough votes that day to get over the reputation cap.
3. Some time later the person cancels his downvote, or it is removed by the serial downvote detection algorithm.
4. Since you were already over the cap for that day, the (+2 rep) from the cancelled downvote had no effect.

Comment: Actually, the situation you described has happened to me multiple times before, I actually do get the +2 on my visible rep - even after hitting the repcap. So I noticed something was odd when I realized that the downvote had disappeared, but I never noticed a +2 in my visible rep over the last few days.

Comment: @Mysticial You can get a +2 when you are already at 200, if you accept an answer for your own questions.

Comment: I misread your comment the first time. Yes, I'm aware you get +2 uncapped rep from accepting. But that wasn't the case. I've only asked one question and it was quite a while ago.