# Badge criteria is not fulfilled even i got 2 badges

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign

Today I got 2 silver badges and 1 bronze badge on StackOverflow, but I think something is wrong there.

[image]

Guru badge: Accepted answer and score of 40 or more. This badge can be awarded multiple times. I got this badge for the Question: [Change title bar text in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438276/change-title-bar-text-in-android/3438352#3438352) but my answer is upvoted only 38 times where as criteria is 40 or more.

Good Question badge: Question score of 25 or more. This badge can be awarded multiple times. I got this badge for the question: [Drawable-hdpi, Drawable-mdpi, Drawable-ldpi Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263265/drawable-hdpi-drawable-mdpi-drawable-ldpi-android) but its is voted for only 24 times where as criteria is 25 or more.

Is there anything wrong or is my question just a stupid question?

Comment: Wild stab in the dark: now invisible votes from deleted users. I have no basis for this even being a valid answer.

Comment: Second wild stab in the dark: people accidentally voting then taking it back, but not before you got the badges.  I also have no basis for my theory.

Comment: Yes i agree with **Both**  of you, i have came across these cases in past.

Comment: Similar situation here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114813/votes-gone-missing Except that I actually did observe the vote count go up to 26 (and getting the badge) before it dropped down to 24. Turns out one of the commenters got deleted. (and probably a few other voters got deleted as well)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like a user went on an upvote spree tripping some warning systems (automated and mod flags) and was deleted, but the badges awarded between the voting activity and the user's deletion.

The fact that someone *barely* pushed you over the limit like this means it's not worth reverting.

For anyone wanting to try this on their own to cheat on badges: if you create sock puppet accounts to do this, rest assured we'll nuke the badges and suspend you *very* quickly, I recommend against it.

Comment: Sir i haven't created any puppet kind of account. Please check my SO activity. Instead there is something with Stackoverflow, please check my another question posted by me today: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118114/badge-criteria-is-not-fulfilled-even-i-got-2-badges

Comment: Any my question is not like "why i didn't get badge yet even there is enough vote.....etc. etc.", instead my question is about to aware why i got badges even there is no fulfillment of criteria of a particular badge.

Comment: @PareshMayani - I think its clear that he is talking about anyone trying to cheat the system to get badges and not you that are trying to clarified what happened. If you were one of them, then you surely would've  received a warning of some kind.

Comment: @Paresh - I wasn't accusing you...that was a warning to others seeing what happened to you as a valid way to sneak in some badges, not what happened to you.

Comment: @NickCraver ok fine. Sorry...

Comment: @Lamak ready for that case but as i am doing stackoverflow in a good manner that warning is not going to be happened in my case.